# Get all blocks in a post/page in WordPress with graphql

Tags: wordpress, graphql, wordpress-gutenberg

We're building a Gatsby site off a WordPress CMS. We're passing post content as an HTML string to Gatsby and just spitting it out on the page, not rebuilding the blocks in Gatsby. So all we need to know is what blocks are in a post/page so we can prepare some other things in Gatsby (interactivity). We can get the top-level/root block list easily, but for nested blocks, it seems like we basically have to guess how many levels it might be. So our query is like this:

```
query MyQuery {
  page(id: "36889", idType: DATABASE_ID) {
    id
    blocks {
      name
      innerBlocks {
        name
        innerBlocks {
          name
          innerBlocks {
            name
            innerBlocks {
              name
              innerBlocks {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**My question is:** Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `blocksJSON` field provides all blocks as one large, nested JSON. It would be great to get that data flattened, but anyway, there is the answer to my question. Something like this:

```
query MyQuery {
  blockEditorContentNodes(where: {title: "My page"}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        blocksJSON
      }
    }
  }
}
```